# VBA Converting DD/mmm/YY column to date

Tags: vba, excel

I have some columns of dates, stored as strings in this format (dd/mmm/yy) and I need to convert them to dates. The problem I'm having is it not any VBA function is able to recognize this string as date.

```
06/Jul/18
20/Jun/18
18/May/18
16/Apr/18
```

The CDate function gives error, and I was thinking somehow parsing the data to make VBA able to read them as dates, but first I was wondering if there is another easy solution.

Edit: The dates are saved as General format cells, changing the format manually doesnt help to recognize them as a dates.

Comment: These are dates stored in a range of cells and the cells are formatted as _Text_?  I'm having no problems converting:  `cdate(Range("A1"))`, `cdate(cstr(Range("A1")))`, `cdate("06/Jul/18")`.  Not sure what could be causing the problem.

Comment: Do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVyXZ.gif) but choose DMY instead of MDY.

Comment: Are you sure you have the "dd/mmm/yy" format? On my PC I only had "d/mmm/yy" (one "d" character). Creating this one format is working fine now.

Comment: The dates are saved as General format cells, changing the format manually doesnt help to recognize them as a dates.

Comment: What is your Windows Regional Settings short-date format?

Answer (score 0):

Problems were caused by the Windows Regional Settings in my laptop.